# How does iterating over strings in C work?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

Wondering why both of these methods work:

String declared via char pointer

```
char *a = "Hello";
```

Iterating over the pointer works regardless if I de-reference it or not. Why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c\n", a[i]); // prints Hello
        printf("%c\n", *a[i]); // also prints Hello
    }
```

I understand that a character pointer points to the first element of the array when using to create a string. Does the compiler automatically know to continuing moving to the adjacent memory slot of a character pointer even if I don't de-reference it?

EDIT

```
printf("%c\n", *a[i]);
```

Throws a compile error, but the program still runs.

Comment: Don't you tell the program how to move to the next character by using a `for` loop?

Comment: Assuming both variants work, shouldn't this print `HHeelllloo`?

Comment: @mkrieger1it does but I run with only one printf, i included both for show.

Comment: Both gcc and clang give an error on the line `printf("%c\n", *a[i]);`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel MSVC, CL.exe

Comment: @madmonkey: Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 also gives me an error on that line: `error C2100: illegal indirection`. Please provide a [mre], which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: So, I apologize, I was missing the compile error, that being said, the program still runs correctly.

Comment: @madmonkey your code do not compile, you can't run it.

Comment: It looks to me as if you compiled the correct version of the program, then changed the code and got a compilation error, and then ran the previously compiled executable again.

Comment: I suggest that you go on `Build`->`Clean Solution` and then try again. That way, you will not be able to execute an older version of the code by mistake, as previously built executables will have been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

On `gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110`

The line

```
printf("%c\n", *a[i]); // also prints Hello
```

gives a compilation error:

```
invalid type argument of unary '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives a compiler error with gcc

> error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

And even if it compiled properly, it would probably crash, as you are dereferencing an unknown memory address, for example for `i` equal `0`, `a[i]` would be `'H'` (`0x48`), and if you dereference the memory address `0x48`, most probably you get a memory fault error.

Thinking about this, I guess language shouldn't allow to dereference an address computed dynamically, for this you have to use a pointer variable.